# Has anyone encountered "Win32 Error : The network path was not found" trying to copy files with FinalBuilder 6?

Tags: deployment, xcopy, network-share, finalbuilder

I have a FinalBuilder job that, as a final step, deploys the compiled app and DLLs to a network share on another server.

About 50% of the time, it just fails with

> Win32 Error : The network path was not found

Changing the target from \\myserver\myshare to \\myserver.mydomain.com\myshare will often fix it temporarily - the first 2-3 runs after modifying the build file will work, after which it'll start failing again.

The FinalBuilder task is running with domain credentials granting admin access on the target box; and copying files to/from shares on that server via Windows Explorer works reliably.

I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally tracked this down. The target server was a virtual machine, and the Hyper-V host network settings were set to "Virtual Network" instead of "Virtual Teamed Network"

I have no idea what that means, but having changed it to Virtual Teamed Network, it works flawlessly. O_o

Answer (score 0):

The network path was not found.

This is related to DNS/WINS not being able to look up the name.     When I have seen this there are problems with our DNS servers.

Adding an Entry into the [lmhost file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMHOSTS) would prevent the system from looking in DNS/WINS.

If that does not work, another option to consider is to increase the number of retries on the Action.   This can be done from the "Runtime" tab of the action by clicking on "Timing Properties"